WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d Error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested
I just installed Wsl2 and i also download Ubuntu but while trying to lauching it brought out this problem "WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d
Error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested.
